# In python I am trying to make a simple english sentence. Please help:

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to use def and I am struggling with my code:

```
def ask():
     noun_1=raw_input("Enter a noun:")
     verb=raw_input("Enter a verb:")
     adjective=raw_input("Enter a adjective:")
     noun_2=raw_input("Enter another noun:")
def main():
     ask()
     print noun_1,verb,adjective,noun_2
main()
```

Comment: put `print noun_1,verb,adjective,noun_2` under `ask()` not `main()` as the namespaces are function scope and is not visible in `main()`

Comment: `noun_1, verb, adjective, noun_2` is not global variables. They will vanish as soon as the `ask` function return. You should put the `print` command inside the `ask` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand variable scope. Basically the variables are defined only in the `ask` function without access in the `main` function. Thus you need to define them as globals.

```
noun_1 = ""
noun_2 = ""
verb = ""
adjective = ""

def ask():
    global noun_1, noun_2, verb, adjective
    noun_1=raw_input("Enter a noun:")
    verb=raw_input("Enter a verb:")
    adjective=raw_input("Enter a adjective:")
    noun_2=raw_input("Enter another noun:")

def main():
    ask()
    print noun_1,verb,adjective,noun_2

main()
```

At the request of many people, you can alternatively return the values in `main` function:

```
def ask():
    noun_1=raw_input("Enter a noun:")
    verb=raw_input("Enter a verb:")
    adjective=raw_input("Enter a adjective:")
    noun_2=raw_input("Enter another noun:")
    return noun_1,verb,adjective,noun_2

def main():
    noun_1,verb,adjective,noun_2 = ask()
    print noun_1,verb,adjective,noun_2

main()
```

Comment: Now both functions can access the variables because they are defined outside both.

Comment: It would be preferable to have ask returning the 3 variables and reasigning it in main scope rather than using globals.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi using global variables all over the place is rarely the right way to go, I have to go with Rafael here.

Comment: There's no real reason to return a list instead of a tuple with the normal syntax. And concatenating strings in a loop is also not a good idea (don't do O(n^2) if you don't have to). Use `' '.join()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the problem is with scope -- the variables don't exist in `main()`. But better than defining a global variable would be to *return* the values from the `ask` function.

```
def ask():
    noun_1 = raw_input("Enter a noun:")
    verb = raw_input("Enter a verb:")
    adjective = raw_input("Enter a adjective:")
    noun_2 = raw_input("Enter another noun:")
    return noun_1, verb, adjective, noun_2

def main():
    a, b, c, d = ask()
    print a, b, c, d

main()
```

With **very** few exceptions, avoiding global variables is a good idea.

Comment: I find ``print ' '.join(ask())`` (or ``print(*ask())``) in Python 3) easier to maintain (if ask start returning less or more variables, it won't break anything.)

Comment: I agree, but the idea of the example is to show how to return and unpack a tuple. Also, for uses where the format of the tuple is part of the contact (think dict.items), you probably **want** your code to break if anything changes.

Comment: I think it is a fine answer, I'm just adding to it. Anyway, I want my tests to break, not my code. If my contract changes, then some test must alert. However, when using a function, I try to be as little restrictive of its contract as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you would need to learn the difference between [local and global variables](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php)

Since noun_1, verb, adjective and noun_2 are local to ask(), you cannot access them via main()

A more elegant:

```
def ask():
  noun_1=raw_input("Enter a noun:")
  verb=raw_input("Enter a verb:")
  adjective=raw_input("Enter a adjective:")
  noun_2=raw_input("Enter another noun:")
  return (noun_1,verb,adjective,noun_2)
if __name__ ==  "__main__":
  (noun_1, verb, adjective, noun_2) = ask()
  print noun_1,verb,adjective,noun_2
```

__name__ == "__main__" is a better way to call the main function